# Django - merge two querysets by sorting them

Tags: python, django

i have two models and i am querying them like this:

```
firstq = FirstModel.objects.order_by('-addedtime')
secondq = SecondModel.objects.order_by('-addedtime')
```

I want to merge and sort them by `addedtime` field. they both have this field..

how do i do it?

`|` works only if i have 2 queries from same model. But i have 2 different models here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do something like:

```
 from itertools import chain
 result_list = list(chain(firstq, secondq))
```

Comment: Will this evaluate `firstq` and `secodq`?

Comment: it doesnt mix them for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

***I think this can help you***

```
from itertools import chain
def get_all_data():
    first = FirstModel.objects.filter()
    second = SecondModel.objects.filter()
    result_list = sorted(
        chain(first, second),
        key=lambda data: data.addedtime, reverse=True)
    return result_list
```